# Azure Event Hub: message-contents-driven metrics

Tags: azure, metrics

Event Hub has a builtin `Incoming Messages` metric which shows how many messages were received but it does not allow to see what those messages are.

I am looking for a simple solution to have a metric based on messages contents. For example, assuming that messages contain a numeric field called `temperature`, how to setup a chart with average temperature? Do I need to install third-party tools like Kibana?